# Visual Studio Code - Microsoft Black Formatter from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting, python-black

I have the Microsoft Black Formatter extension in VSCode (in WSL, inside Windows 11). I can format opened python files with no problem, one-by-one, either using keyboard shortcut or right click on the file and select "Format Document". So the extension works as it supposed to.

My question: can I run the bundled `black` executable of this extension from the command line (CLI)?

Ps.: I would like to format whole folders, recursively. Of course, I can install a separate `black` executable from a python (anaconda) package, and use that from the CLI as any other UNIX command, but I would like to at least try use the bundled version from the extension, if that's possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the extension folder in a command line, but that path will change with updates.

On Windows cmd:

```
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.black-formatter-2023.6.0\bundled\libs
python -m black my_file_or_folder.py
```

Linux/MacOS:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.black-formatter-2023.6.0/bundled/libs
python -m black my_file_or_folder.py
```

Or you can use the one-liner on a unix-based OS:

```
PYTHONPATH=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.black-formatter-2023.6.0/bundled/libs python -m black my_file_or_folder.py
```

On WSL, the path is different, but the method is the same as Linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/mnt/c/Users/User/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.black-formatter-2023.6.0/bundled/libs
python -m black my_file_or_folder.py
```

You can glob the version in smarter shells to avoid issues when updating, but cmd is pretty simple in this regard and doesn't help much.

Comment: Thanks, the WSL example works nicely. And if you don't want `black` to replace single quotes with double quotes (which is its default behavior), you would need to use the `-S` command line switch like this: `python -m black -S my_file_or_folder.py`